# Having a problem with low frame rate and performance in unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

Actually I do have a big problem with performance in my game and also I have checked a lot of resources and I did what they said about this topic but unfortunately I still have a problem with that.

Also, I did all of these subjects below to solve my issue, but nothing happened

1. mapping(I set all of my GameObjects as static object)
2. re-size all of textures in the game
3. customize all of my Audio
4. used low poly objects in game
5. baking
6. checking profiler

on medium range phone frame rate is around 30-40 fps
also I de-active all of my objects in runtime (such as UI , 3D Models , Terrian and etc. ... ) just for testing to get know what the problem is ?

But the funny part is:
when I de-active them, my frame rate is still 35-45 FPS.

I'm really confused about that !!

**update :** 
Also my game is for android platform

I uploaded some pictures of my game profiler
[Cpu Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hspHf.jpg)

[Rendering Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HgUv.jpg)

[Cpu Timeline Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1dlG.jpg)

[Audio Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PfJM.jpg)

[UI Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kua9O.jpg)

[Physic Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqkQS.jpg)

[Global Illumination Profiler picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t3Pu.jpg)

Comment: you first have to find out it's about GPU or CPU using profiler, any idea about that?

Comment: Did you put all the rigidbody calculations into the fixedupdate function and not the update function?

Comment: @DevsterLp , Basically my game is Endless(Runner) game and all of my objects in my game does not have any rigidbody , they are just moving forward by transform but the only object which has rigidbody is my main character .
All of my transform calculations is under Update function . any suggestion ??

Comment: @Hesamom Actually, I have checked profiler and my average base on TRIS and VERTS are between 70k-100k and TOTAL-BATCHES and DRAWCALLS  are near 250 and SET-PASS-CALL is almost 186 and they are all in under rendering panel . 
Also in profiler I see WaitForTargetFPS , Camera.Render and VSync under cpu panel ! I'm really confused about that ?? Do u have any suggestion ?

Comment: things seem pretty fine in the profiler, perhaps your testing the game on a low-end Android phone? also, what's your backend scripting? Mono or IL2CPP? the second can hugely increase the performance, you can as well enable "Graphics job" and compare the difference.

Comment: @Hesamom  
Actually we have tested on a low-end Android phone(We developed our game for medium phone above and ignore  low-end phone) as well and our fps game is between 15- 20 .
Also we selected IL2CPP and Graphics job for our game . Our problem is on medium range phone we do have lags and delay also I need to mentioned that  I de-active all of my objects in runtime (such as UI , 3D Models , Terrian and etc. ... ) just for testing to get know what the problem is ?
But still
when I de-active them, my frame rate is still 35-45 FPS. Why Do u think it is like that ???